# AoCG2021 Day 10: Memory reallocation routine

Tags: code-golf, array

Part of [**Advent of Code Golf 2021**](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/24068/78410) event. See the linked meta post for details.

Related to [AoC2017 Day 6](https://adventofcode.com/2017/day/6).

---

A debugger program here is having an issue: it is trying to repair a memory reallocation routine, but it keeps getting stuck in an infinite loop.

In this area, there are `n` memory banks; each memory bank can hold any number of blocks. The goal of the reallocation routine is to balance the blocks between the memory banks.

The reallocation routine operates in cycles. In each cycle, it finds the memory bank with the most blocks (ties won by the lowest-numbered memory bank) and redistributes those blocks among the banks. To do this, it removes all of the blocks from the selected bank, then moves to the next (by index) memory bank and inserts one of the blocks. It continues doing this until it runs out of blocks; if it reaches the last memory bank, it wraps around to the first one.

For example, if there are initially four banks with `[0, 2, 7, 0]` memory blocks:

- The third bank is freed, and starting with the next (fourth) bank, the 7 blocks are cyclically spread out over the memory banks. After one cycle, the result looks like `[2, 4, 1, 2]`:

  ```
   0   2   0   0
              +1
  +1  +1  +1  +1
  +1  +1
  --------------
   2   4   1   2
  ```
- In the next cycle, the second bank is freed and redistributed, resulting in `[3, 1, 2, 3]`.
- In the next cycle, the first bank is freed (when there are ties, the first bank is chosen), giving `[0, 2, 3, 4]`.
- Next cycles give `[1, 3, 4, 1]`, then `[2, 4, 1, 2]`, where the sequence forms a loop.

Your job is to simulate one cycle of memory reallocation.

Standard [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules apply. The shortest code in bytes wins.

### Test cases

```
[0, 2, 7, 0] -> [2, 4, 1, 2] -> [3, 1, 2, 3] -> [0, 2, 3, 4]
-> [1, 3, 4, 1] -> [2, 4, 1, 2]
[3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9, 2] -> [5, 2, 5, 2, 6, 1, 4]
-> [6, 3, 6, 3, 0, 2, 5] -> [0, 4, 7, 4, 1, 3, 6]
-> [1, 5, 1, 5, 2, 4, 7] -> [2, 6, 2, 6, 3, 5, 1]
-> [3, 0, 3, 7, 4, 6, 2] -> [4, 1, 4, 1, 5, 7, 3]
-> [5, 2, 5, 2, 6, 1, 4]
```

Comment: Wdym? i don't understand.

Comment: I believe all Santa's and these debuggers should learn something about NP-Hard first.

Comment: Suggested test cases: `[10, 3, 10] -> [3, 7, 13] -> [8, 11, 4] -> [12, 3, 8] -> [4, 7, 12] -> [8, 11, 4]` (or any other where both the input and output contains at least one multi-digit number).

Answer (score 6):

## [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/), 33 [bytes](https://github.com/mlochbaum/BQN/blob/master/commentary/sbcs.bqn)

```
{+˝↑‿(≠)⥊∾(⥊⟜0∾(-∾⥊⟜1)∘⊑⟜)⊑⍒}
```

[Try it online!](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=RiDihpAgeyvLneKGkeKAvyjiiaDwnZWpKeKlivCdlaniiL4o4qWK4p+cMOKIvigt4oi+4qWK4p+cMSniiJjiipHin5zwnZWpKeKKkeKNkvCdlal9CgooM+KAvzHigL804oC/MeKAvzXigL854oC/MinigL8oMOKAvzLigL834oC/MCl7a+KGkPCdlajii4Q+ez7iiJhG4o2f8J2VqSBrfcKo4oaV8J2VqX3CqCA54oC/Ng==)

```
{+˝↑‿(≠)⥊∾(⥊⟜0∾(-∾⥊⟜1)∘⊑⟜)⊑⍒} # Example input:  = 0 2 7 0
                                ⊑⍒  # The first index of the maximum value  2
                           ⊑⟜      # The value at that index               7
                    -∾⥊⟜1           # negative value, value many 1's
                                     # ¯7 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
             ⥊⟜0∾                   # Prepend index many 0's
                                     # 0 0 ¯7 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
          ∾                         # 0 2 7 0 0 0 ¯7 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
   ↑‿(≠)⥊                           # Reshape into a matrix with length() columns, padding the last row with 0's
 +˝                                  # sum the columns
```

Answer (score 5):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 37 bytes

```
(0:`]`[}+/@,-@#@[]\0,0 1#~],{~)]i.>./
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/NQysEmITomu19R10dB2UHaJjYwx0DBQMletidarrNGMz9ez09P9rcnGlJmfkK6TFWWnYmGnGKhjoKBjpKJgDTYNIqKsjKTA0AKow1lEw1FEwAZOmOgqWQA3/AQ)

Consider input `0 2 7 0`:

- `(...)]i.>./` Entire verb is a hook giving the verb in parens the original input as a left arg, and the
  max value's index `i.>/.` as the right.  It evaluates like:

  ```
  0 2 7 0 (...) 2  NB. 2 is the index of 7.
  ```
- `(0 1#~],{~)` Append the max's index to the max
  `],{~` and copy `0 1` elementwise that many times:

  ```
  0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
  ```
- `0,` Prepend another 0:

  ```
  0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
  ```
- `-@#@[]\` Fold that into original-input-sized chunks, filling empty slots in
  the last row with 0:

  ```
  0 0 0 1
  1 1 1 1
  1 1 0 0
  ```
- `` 0:`]`[}..., `` Prepend to that the original list, with the max value zeroed
  out:

  ```
  0 2 0 0
  0 0 0 1
  1 1 1 1
  1 1 0 0
  ```
- `+/@` And sum the rows:

  ```
  2 4 1 2
  ```

Comment: Sum the columns, no?

Comment: @Neil Depends on how you look at it: sum the rows to each other in their entirety, or individually calculate the sum of each column

Comment: Neil We put a plus between each row, sum happens elementwise, so it results in column sums

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 84 bytes

```r
function(a){v=a[i<-which.max(a)]+1;a[i]=0;while(v<-v-1)a[i]=a[i<-i%%sum(a|1)+1]+1;a}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYzLDoIwFAX3/YpuSNpwayhKfEC/xLAoxIabQDEVqon67bU2btycxWTmuGBUMKvtF5wt0/zplT5jI@4D9sNm0o/I2lzWEbaqqCMeL8w3wgvJE0s2ZtltnZh@SZ7LpL@DVj0roIQ9FJyY2TGkaKk8Vfzq0C5MN8LEc05IF80tUAl0l7YCegRa/lWHX9V9qy5W4QM)

Note that in `a[i]=a[i<-i%%sum(a|1)+1]+1`, `i` is first updated on the RHS and then substitution is performed with the same index on LHS and RHS.

Comment: Nice.  I had a [slightly similar approach](https://tio.run/##RYzBCsIwEETvfkUvhV2SQuJFsO6XlB4kNBgwG6gtrKjfHhOreJl5bw4z58STu7vrRJ6yX9ktITEIPmSIpy6eF3cBriBl1IIjmd6nGUITuAF75M6qiG17WyPI06KyKEMYqYayvbwyCDkweq8P2iDufPkpUWvrD/1wk799HfMb) initially, but annoyingly also 84 bytes, no matter how much I tried to tweak it...

Comment: ...so [now it's your turn](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/238322/95126)...!

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), 66 bytes

Updates the input array.

```javascript
a=>{for(a[i=a.indexOf(m=Math.max(...a))]=0;m--;)a[++i%a.length]++}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hcxLCoMwGATgvaf4N4WEPLBvJKTgAUoPIC5@bNQUTYpKEcSzp7arli66GZiB@W74wL7o7H0Qzl9NKHVAfZpK3xHMrEZp3dWMl5K0@oxDLVsciZQSKc11rFohFMWMMbtC2RhXDXXO2BwK73rfGNn4iqSgIYs5bDgcOcQ5jV64W9aDAiGcojBBSVKq4Ou29DmKfqQthzWH3Tv3HJIF/iCTv2R4Ag)

Answer (score 3):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 65 bytes

```
a->for(i=1,c=a[m=vecsort(-a,,1)[1]],a[(m+i-1)%#a+1]+=1);a[m]-=c;a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HczdCsIwDAXgVwkToWEpLP6gMrIXKbkIw0lBXalD8Olrt5vA4TsnyXL0j1QmkGJ@mObsojCNYuEl3/v4mfPivBExBlYlC@7VRs@431nL2gpjX6vqZeytWErPnzPwA2yfQIAJrgQpx/dSoVmpAaswOUNEghA6ggPBhaDTGo@0bk7bPRPcKqpi@QM)

---

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 69 bytes

```
a->c=a[m=vecsort(-a,,1)[1]];a+Vecrev((x^c\(x-1)-c/x)*x^m%(1-x^#a),#a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HctdCsIwEATgqywVYVc32PiDiqTH8KWmsIRWCtaGWEo8fUx9mIHhY7yEXj196sAkUZUzUg9mbt1nDBMqYdZUa2tvsr23LrQzYmzcA6PSpNwu0iY2wxq1is1KiHOSeP/6ooCqoBsD9mBAM1wYfOjfU4ZioQIkQ4dCRAx1XTLsGc4Mpc3zwMvn@O8TwzWjtZR@)

Longer but more interesting.

See the input as a polynomial, e.g. `[0, 2, 7, 0]` becomes \$2x+7x^2\$. Let \$c\ x^{m-1}\$ be its term with the largest coefficient (in this case, \$c=7,m=3\$). Then we subtract \$c\ x^{m-1}\$ from the polynomial, and then add \$(x^m+x^{m+1}+\cdots+x^{m+c-1}) \bmod (x^n-1)\$, where \$n\$ is the length of the input.

Comment: Cool.  Why is it `mod (x^n - 1)`?

Comment: @Jonah \$x^{k\ n+r} \bmod (x^n-1) = x^r\$, where \$0\le r<n\$.

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 59 bytes

```ruby
->a{a[i=a.index(m=a.max)]=0;m.times{a[a[i+=1]?i:i=0]+=1};a}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYpRC4IwFIXf/RX2EmpXmVZEzWs/5HIfFqkMmrSlYMh@@xr0cOA73zlueXzDgKHs1KZIo6r09OzXzEQyas0ZhTTVrE3/iXt8HLDmu75pFBzRS@XDiGVnoXBb5trWSosDUWGZ82Wa9St1e7K8Q2LpfJK805FIQAMXEMz/eoQaTjFnuEITZfgB)

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>78</s> 77 bytes

*Edit: -1 byte and re-arranged to an almost-readable format thanks to pajonk*

```r
function(x){x[m<-match(n<-max(x),x)]=0;a=x%*%t(!1:n);a[m+1:n]=1;rowSums(a)+x}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYvRCoIwGEbvfYp1Ifx/TnCWVOqeokvxYg6lQZuxJi2iZ18zuunm4/Bxjg2zGeVTXkc@8TAtRjo1G/D48p1ucy2cvIBZwceTeux50Qju023qYMNqg43odBah56yx8@O86DsIzPw7gOASClrSAy0Qk2m2oIgyhNUV3qwyDkSbT1HGJIEhujtKGCX771aUnCgp/7vjrxvWbkAMHw)

First we construct a matrix `a` of length(`x`) rows and `n`=max(`x`) zeros (using a golfy trick: `x%*%t(!1:n)`).
[R](https://www.r-project.org/) fills matrices row-first if we use 1-dimensional indices, so we can fill the matrix with `1`s at positions from `m+1` up to `m+n`, where `m` is the position of the maximum element of `x`, and the row sums will give the amounts we need to add to each index of `x`.
So now we just need to set the `m`-th element of `x` to zero, and add the row sums of `a`.

Comment: Yeah, I played with rowSums and matrices, but didn't get to `%*%` trick. Well done!

Comment: [77 bytes](https://tio.run/##VYtBDoIwFET3nKIuSP6XT0JRoiI9hUtiAjQ0NrGtqRBrjGdHMG7czExm5vnJ2V4@5bUXSkxqtHLQzkLAV6hNlZp2kBewSwhzSQHPIjt69ziN5g5NXaUNhHgdD7DipUUyyWzEEZPwnqAVEjLKaUcZYqScB820Zbws8Oa1HaCtUgXtvEXQzd8NMU5s@9WC2IFY/s/tf1y3cB3i9AE "R – Try It Online"). [Slightly more readable?](https://tio.run/##VYvRCoIwGEbvfYp1Ifx/TnCWVOqeokvxYg6lQZuxJi2iZ18zuunm4/Bxjg2zGeVTXkc@8TAtRjo1G/D48p1ucy2cvIBZwceTeux50Qju023qYMNqg43odBah56yx8@O86DsIzPw7gOASClrSAy0Qk2m2oIgyhNUV3qwyDkSbT1HGJIEhujtKGCX771aUnCgp/7vjrxvWbkAMHw "R – Try It Online")

Comment: Thanks!  And, yes, the readable version is indeed much nicer...

Answer (score 2):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), 78 bytes

```c
h;m;i;f(*b,n){for(i=m=0;i<n;++i)m=m<b[i]?b[h=i]:m;for(b[h]=0;m--;)++b[++h%n];}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVTbjpswEH3frxghZQXB0XLNateh@1D1KxJUAYGN1eBEgapRI3696cBg7K0S7UtR4jE@xzNzTuwUi2KfyffrdcdrLnhlz3MmnUt1ONkiqROPi5XkriucOqlX@Vqkb/l6l4j0teY9B19SJNWLBXdcN1@77m4mU95dhWyhzoS0Hbg8AD79Qls2rbdOIYGLxyBg8MzA6/iE@YQhEDHwkWFgAWEhAQxCAwvNnMiIDCwizCcAdxtYbOakkjGDl4@Fl0SKh@Q0LmmDQfouiRUNeaYP6nvuuNI/H6gNMQcvGMmmEFAIKUQUYgpLnQXK87Es2nLr3XFL4f4dxxQe3HFN4eEd5xQefVI//sw4RRwdXg6FaKSmYtM7xSbyZALTevU00NNQTyM9jfVUWVscZNNCsctOcxzL4kd5olLW5vwt2JxfvuI3thiY76E17sbLAHYvSshtecZtHh@nK2jE7/JQ2aqg8zQuzKcVDnjFera6Leq3lphpPF8DnnITxgM14s1tOP9ZVcios/3@UNgS5hA5mnI8IamyrbVlLGohowgUIIf@zN7M7bNmtkVbxFvvzauFY4v/E0bK/uk7wdW@XQwa63Rhu@cwkDc6TGHxBT60SUcC003H4oYBcMyaBjn@/5U3avlH4VDrMdFKsbc7UrWsWbORmFGdtz6Hyts9dNc/RbXP3pvr4tdf)

Inputs a pointer to an array of memory banks and its length (because pointers in C carry no length info).
Reallocates the memory in place - of course!!! :)))

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 27 bytes

```
ＩＥθ⁺∧⁻⌕θ⌈θκι÷⁺⌈θ﹪⁻⌕θ⌈θκＬθＬθ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM5sbhEwzexQKNQRyEgp7RYwzEvRcM3Mw/IcssEMoHCvokVmbmluRqFmpo6CtlAnAnEnnklLpllmSmpGmBdCDVA9fkppTn5hAzxSc1LL8kA8VE5QGD9/390tLGOgqGOggmYNNVRsNRRMIqN/a9blgMA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: The number to be added to each cell (or replacing the maximum cell) equals the maximum cell divided by the length of the array, but adjusting for the cyclic difference between the two cells, which distributes the remainder.

```
  θ                         Input array
 Ｅ                          Map over elements
       θ                    Input array
      ⌕                     Find index of
         θ                  Input array
        ⌈                   Maximum value
     ⁻                      Minus
          κ                 Current index
    ∧                       Logical And
           ι                Current value
   ⁺                        Plus
               θ            Input array
              ⌈             Maximum value
             ⁺              Plus
                   θ        Input array
                  ⌕         Find index of
                     θ      Input array
                    ⌈       Maximum value
                 ⁻          Minus
                      κ     Current index
                ﹪           Modulo
                        θ   Input array
                       Ｌ    Length
            ÷               Integer divided by
                          θ Input array
                         Ｌ  Length
Ｉ                           Cast to string
                            Implicitly print each value on its own line
```

I misread the question, so I originally wrote a 43 byte program to find the loop:

```
Ｗ¬№υθ«⊞υ✂θＵＭθ⁺∧⁻⌕θ⌈θλκ÷⁺⌈θ﹪⁻⌕θ⌈θλＬθＬθ»⊞υθＩυ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hY89C8IwEIbn9lfcmEIc/BrESSqCYKXgWDqENphgPmybVEH87fFaEXFyuOOe@@J9K8HayjIVwk1IxYEcrSOp9cYRT6FJkgQecZT7Tgx8UrLiBLvrOMrYNbVaM1OThkKufEc2WGfSYLWT73bG7lJ7PZxQUBgXjL1xW9nLmpPx6ruD@7b2yv57cuDm7MTAv4CynvFHa4OUtxKNpKxDNzgNoSjmFKYUFmNeUlhRmJVlmPTqBQ) Link is to verbose version of code. Outputs using Charcoal's default array format, which is each element on its own line and rows double-spaced.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E (legacy)](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/tree/fb4a2ce2bce6660e1a680a74dd61b72c945e6c3b), <s>19</s> 18 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
DZ©kÅ0®(®Å1)˜IgôζO
```

-1 byte by switching to the legacy version of 05AB1E, where the sum ignores strings inside integer-lists.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##AS0A0v8wNWFiMWX//0Rawqlrw4Uwwq4owq7DhTEpy5xJZ8O0zrZP//9bMCwyLDcsMF0) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##PU47CgIxEL3KspXCK/IPVtvY2xu2UBALeyEHWA9g7QVsthIPkJSCh/AicWYQi2Fe3rxPlN/t9aGd89B3n8u164fc1ttyP9VJlXlR5jrp5euWj/Xxfm4aWkoKBhFqRDJw0DCELG9YQny1cIQ0b@jflZUeK1F70vAE5ukdSMnDXi8ZjhrYQbwkeXFzX5TeIG7HvOQrUrIjSL7790X60/gF).

Luckily we don't have to find the cycle, since that would have been [30 bytes (and very slow)](https://tio.run/##AWAAn/8wNWFiMWX/dnk/IiDihpIgIj95/1tEWsKpa8OFMMKuKMKuw4UxKcuceWfDtM62T0TCu0TCr3PDpSPLhn3LhsKv/yzCtP9bWzAsMiw3LDBdLFszLDEsNCwxLDUsOSwyXV0) due to 05AB1E's lack of get_index builtin for sublists.

**Explanation:**

```python
               #  e.g. input = [0,2,7,0]
D              # Duplicate the (implicit) input-list
               #  STACK: [0,2,7,0],[0,2,7,0]
 Z             # Push its maximum (without popping the list)
               #  STACK: [0,2,7,0],[0,2,7,0],7
  ©            # Store this maximum in variable `®` (without popping)
   k           # Get the 0-based index of this maximum in the list
               #  STACK: [0,2,7,0],2
    Å0         # Pop and push a list of that many 0s
               #  STACK: [0,2,7,0],[0,0]
 ®             # Push the maximum from variable `®`
  (            # Negate it
               #  STACK: [0,2,7,0],[0,0],-7
 ®             # Push the maximum from variable `®` again
  Å1           # Pop and push a list of that many 0s
               #  STACK: [0,2,7,0],[0,0],-7,[1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
      )        # Wrap everything on the stack into a list
       ˜       # Flatten it
               #  STACK: [0,2,7,0,0,0,-7,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
        Ig     # Push the input-length
               #  STACK: [0,2,7,0,0,0,-7,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],4
          ô    # Split the list into parts of that size
               #  STACK: [[0,2,7,0],[0,0,-7,1],[1,1,1,1],[1,1]]
           ζ   # Zip/transpose; swapping rows/columns,
               # using a space as default filler-item if the matrix is irregular
               #  STACK: [[0,0,1,1],[2,0,1,1],[7,-7,1," "],[0,1,1," "]]
            O  # Sum each inner list, ignoring the spaces
               #  STACK: [2,4,1,2]
               # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), <s>81</s> <s>79</s> 77 bytes

```python
def f(a):
 k=a.index(m:=max(a))
 for i in range(k,m-~k):a[i%len(a)]+=i>k or-m
```

-2 bytes thanks to *@loopyWalt*.

Modifies the input-list.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##TY5NDoIwEEb3nGI2hjYOhh9RhNSLEGKaULSpLaSywI1LD@ARvQgWSNTFLOZ9b75Md@8vrUmyzo5jLRpoCKe5B4rxjTS1GIjOmeaDo9SDprUgQRqw3JwFUaiDh6I5L@XqKoxzqjWTRwWtDfTc1otbTziaqXK@Pv2uFwjQWWkmSZia@fB@vsCnxZxMvxT/jtu8ubIMMcY9hhWmji0owQi3blI8YFxh9g2iEF3m3B0txg8)

**Explanation:**

```python
def f(a):     # Function with list parameter:
 k=a.index(m:=max(a))
              #  Set `m` to the maximum of the list
              #  And set `k` to the first 0-based index of this maximum
 for i in range(k,m-~k):
              # Loop `i` in the range [k,m+k]:
   a[i%len(a) #  `i` modulo the list-length to prevent IndexErrors
    ]+=       #  And increase the value at this modular index by:
       i>k    #   1 if `i` is larger than `k`
        or-m  #   or the negative maximum otherwise (if i==k in the first iteration)
```

Comment: There seems to be a useless semicolon. And an additional byte can be saved in the last line https://tio.run/##TY5NDoIwEEb3nGI2hjYOhh9RhNSLEGKaULSpLaSywI1LD@ARvQgWSNTFLOZ9b75Md@8vrUmyzo5jLRpoCKe5B4rxjTS1GIjOmeaDo9SDprUgQRqw3JwFUaiDh6I5L@XqKoxzqjWTRwWtDfTc1otbTziaqXK@Pv2uFwjQWWkmSZia@fB@vsCnxZxMvxT/jtu8ubIMMcY9hhWmji0owQi3blI8YFxh9g2iEF3m3B0txg8

Comment: @loopywalt Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, 85 bytes

```java
a->{int l=0,m=0,j=0;for(int i:a){if(i>m){m=i;j=l;}l++;}for(a[j]=0;m-->0;)a[++j%l]++;}
```

Modifies the input-array.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##hVDdaoMwFL7vUxwKA8UYXLeyrUFhD7De9FK8OLM6kiWxaOwokmd3SfSujF0kkO@c7y8Cr5iK8/dcSxwG@ECupw0A16bpW6wbOPonwLXjZ6gjh5cVYMwcaDfuGgwaXsMRNOQzpsXkNkDmGVHuiDxjbdd7FvADxhNvI16oeFI5ZyKXzMokYdavYCkqt63StMhYjGWSiAdZ@enMvM9l/JTOZ7ULaZTLGp1Mz/VXyLQENc1gIt38QIg6ZWRHXkhmyT5kvps/kUfy7M6evJGdJa93zYJVIK3d@x5vxLMBVTdqs/r6EmxBlg4LDHC6DaZRtBsNvbisJhLuy@louKTvXmugpltaREE7TrYHgO0aF0DTeh2wPxSl/ldz5dpQzs6/)

**Explanation:**

```java
a->{              // Method with integer-array parameter and no return
  int l=0,        //  Length, starting at 0
      m=0,        //  Max, starting at 0
      j=0;        //  Max-index, starting at 0
  for(int i:a){   //  Foreach over the integers of the input:
    if(i>m){      //   If the current integer is larger than the max
      m=i;        //    Replace the max with this integer
      j=l;}       //    And replace the max-index with the 'length' thus far
    l++;          //   At the end of the iteration, increase the length by 1
  }               //  After the first loop:
  for(a[j]=0;     //  Replace the max at the max-index with 0
      m-->0;)     //  Loop the max amount of times:
    a[++j         //   Increase the max-index by 1 first
         %l       //   Then modulo it by the determined array-length
           ]++;}  //   And increase the integer at that index by 1
```

Comment: Nice use of the `-->` operator ;-)

Answer (score 1):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), 30 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
╙`=º*\ª*hb*\Γ─h(?£/{\;\£‼≥<^mΣ
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7///R1JkJtod2acUcWqWVkaQVc27yoykNGRr2hxbrV8dYxxxa/Khhz6POpTZxuecW//8fbaBjpGOuYxDLFW2kY6JjqGMEZBmDaB1jIAska6xjAmQZgmgdQ6gsSKWpjiVYtSlQDQibgcSBfDOgShAG6TUFm2ECtAGkAygONskUrBtknznYXjOwbmOQONh8AyAbpMMMbL4J3D5zoJsA)

Sometimes this language can be so annoying to program in.. MathGolf lacks a builtin to split integer-lists into sublists; it also lacks a transpose builtin for matrices; the (do-)while builtins only work for everything before it, not for portions near the end; and it lacks a builtin to push an implicit input-list (so those can only be accessed again by swapping) - [using an explicit input-list is also 30 bytes](https://tio.run/##PY0tDsJAEIX9nIQ0k7C/bUjgJg1/AlbQYHCYWjQg0A2mRyCo1vcQe5Fl3grEvGy@/d5Ms7uE4/l0SGnsN/H52q6GT1EPfRH2RT3d46MNs7EfuvkVGdtvvL2X62bqUlJsuGJFhh1rNmSRbAncsiONZJ05DM8Lsbz8YkpQKsXBoOOl6WQjXKGEhs6uUELDZNfnnUpecIWS@1@o2P4A). Because of that, the trailing `h(?£/{\;\£‼≥<^mΣ` does what we we want to do manually (it basically accomplishes the same as `IgôζO` in [my 05AB1E answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/238317/52210), but a lot more hacky..)

**Explanation:**

```python
                #  e.g. input = [0,2,7,0]
╙               # Push the maximum of the (implicit) input-list
                #  STACK: 7
 `              # Duplicate the top two items
                #  STACK: [0,2,7,0],7,[0,2,7,0],7
  =             # Get the 0-based index of this maximum in the list
                #  STACK: [0,2,7,0],7,2
   º*           # Multiply this index by [0]
                #  STACK: [0,2,7,0],7,[0,0]
     \          # Swap the two two items so the max is at the top
                #  STACK: [0,2,7,0],[0,0],7
      ª*        # And multiply this max by [1]
                #  STACK: [0,2,7,0],[0,0],[1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
        h       # Push its length (without popping)
                #  STACK: [0,2,7,0],[0,0],[1,1,1,1,1,1,1],7
         b*     # Multiply it by -1 to negate it
                #  STACK: [0,2,7,0],[0,0],[1,1,1,1,1,1,1],-7
           \    # Swap the top two items
                #  STACK: [0,2,7,0],[0,0],-7,[1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
            Γ─  # Wrap the top four items into a list, and flatten
                #  STACK: [0,2,7,0,0,0,-7,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
```

```python
h               # Push the length (without popping)
                #  STACK: [0,2,7,0,0,0,-7,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],14
 (              # Decrease it by 1
                #  STACK: [0,2,7,0,0,0,-7,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],13
  ?             # Triple-swap to push the (implicit) input-list
                #  STACK: [0,2,7,0,0,0,-7,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],13,[0,2,7,0]
   £            # Pop and push its length
                #  STACK: [0,2,7,0,0,0,-7,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],13,4
    /           # Integer-division
                #  STACK: [0,2,7,0,0,0,-7,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],3
     {          # Loop that many times:
      \         #  Swap to unfortunately get the implicit loop-index at the top
                #   STACK: [0,2,7,0,0,0,-7,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],0
       ;        #  Discard the top of the stack
                #   STACK: [0,2,7,0,0,0,-7,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
        \       #  Swap again to push the (implicit) input-list
                #   STACK: [0,2,7,0,0,0,-7,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[0,2,7,0]
         £      #  Pop and push its length
                #   STACK: [0,2,7,0,0,0,-7,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],4
          ‼     #  Apply the following two builtins separated:
           ≥    #   Slice to get the items in the range [input-length,list-length)
           <    #   Slice to get the items in the range [0,input-length)
                #    STACK: [0,0,-7,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[0,2,7,0]
            ^   #  Zip to create pairs
                #   STACK: [[0,0],[0,2],[-7,7],[1,0],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1]]
             mΣ #  Map, and sum each inner list
                #   STACK: [0,2,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
                # (after the loop, the entire stack joined is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 76 bytes

```php
for($a[$i=array_keys($a=&$argv,$m=max($a))[0]]=0;$m--;)$a[++$i%count($a)]++;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##vY7BCsIwDIbvfYogVSytUOdEpRYfZI4xZuc2WTs2FUV89tpVPMkOXswhCfmT/F9TNHa7a4oGpW2b3pOuKPPzFKft8UqEzU3r@giX8q2e1L1zAznxCwzXsk5vbkBIxONYcoHr2UwQd0IpLseZuej@GYkpFVZlhYGqMzpROjMH9XFByNtUIIELcHULYV8pJQ8ELgYofrP3nwYRngh5bbTXez1ySF5wRNGCwZxB6POSwYZBEItv4vXfia3lNrAry18)

Modifies the input array in place. Now this answer troubles me. In PHP we can take arguments as an array in `$argv`, but the first entry is the file name (`".code.tio"` in TIO), which forces me to do `array_shift($argv)` to get rid of this entry. After [verifying on meta](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20882/90841), we can take the input by reference and change it in place even for a full program, but [cannot assume the input is stored in predefined variables](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8731/90841). If I leave the `array_shift($argv)` as part of the program, it would mean that I consider the input format as different from the question (a string followed by our numeric values), and we cannot loop over it of else the array would shrink with each iteration.. so here are all the versions.. Anyone can rule this out?

## PROBABLY INVALID: [PHP](https://php.net/), 69 bytes

```php
for($a[$i=array_keys($a,$m=max($a))[0]]=0;$m--;)$a[++$i%count($a)]++;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##vY7fCoIwFMbv9xSHWNHYhFVGxRw9iIkM09RwE60oomdfc3UX3UXn4vz9@M6vLVsbbduyRarr1C3ty6o4TbGSE6y6w4UIW5jOzTGu5EtxzG@9WzDcyEZdXUdIzJNEcoGbIBDEaSnF1TgzZz04kYRSYfOsNFD3Rqe5zsw@n77tEfL@NUjgAlyNIBwqpeSOwMVP3nunrwgPhPxttNM7PXJI/uCI4gWDGYPQ5yWDDYN5Ij6J138ntpbbuV1Z/gQ)

**If I had to include the `array_shift($argv)` in the code, it would be shorter to use a function (note that I can't use a loop in a PHP arrow function):**

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 84 bytes

```php
function(&$a){for($a[$i=array_keys($a,$m=max($a))[0]]=0;$m--;)$a[++$i%count($a)]++;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nU7LCsIwELznKxaJ0pAIUSsqMfghtUioKa3SpFQFpfTb41YRBfHiHvYxuzszdVGH9aYuakJzHfKLy86ld9GIGtbmvomoSWipTdOY2@5obycEBK10Za7YMZbINNVS0Wo8VgxvOaflMPMXd@7XKeeqC4oQigSgIZECpgIWAmSqUDDqcaaIzQoPh5N3O@syv7cvnDwcHPBTKsC6hrivnLOWAMaboZ9@sXTkKTDYuq0bfLiZCZgIiB95LmCF5tDWl@byH80QZJiGRZB3)

Answer (score 1):

## TypeScript Types, 584 bytes

```
//@ts-ignore
type a<T,K=keyof T>=T extends T?keyof T extends K?T:never:0;type b<T,U=T>=T extends T?Exclude<T,Partial<Exclude<U,T>>>:0;type c<T,N=[]>=`${T}`extends`${N["length"]}`?N:c<T,[...N,0]>;type d<A,B,N=[]>=A extends[...B,...infer A]?d<A,B,[...N,0]>:[N,A];type M<A,T={[K in keyof A]:c<A[K]>},i=a<{[K in keyof T]:T[K]extends b<T[number]>?c<K>:never}[number]>,I=i["length"],X=d<T[I],c<T["length"]>>>={[K in keyof T]:(K extends`${I}`?X[0]:[...X[0],...T[K],...c<K>extends[...i,...Partial<X[1]>]|Partial<[...i,...X[1]]extends[...c<T["length"]>,...infer A]?A:never>?[0]:[]])["length"]}
```

[Try It Online!](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTACBcGcFoEsHMB2B7ATgUwFDgJ4Ad0ACAQwB4AVAGgGkBeAa3R2QDNDyA+W8w9AD3DpEAE0jsA-I2Zse-QSLHVx5AFyJ0AN3SoVABgDcuAoQBGFSgFVuXWQKGiJAUT4BjADYBXYenMAFYqjgsMRupM7uXj4WlJwcHHqG+EQu5gBytADaALpcAAYAJADe5AC+uXL2kAWFqRkARG5C8OAAFnVZZeKpKilUGQB0g6mUujmJxsKkAIKUAEKU6dlcU7x2CgOD84P9sIgs2oRTWeKTM-Mb-cOj8RnDR+NEALLTMbSFGdSEu4RSrIdZPWmHxyJUosFoZHen2+vxkAPIwIqClMFAyiA8AFsTNocuIUtR4uotKgSmjMdjUDlKABJWiweqNRDNNpZSgADVokwR1NZvQZTVa7TiXChX0QPyYf3IAIAFJ8kaJqtTOmyMqMVBdVaNKNsEdRWdt8RwFZALrAdYN-IFgqFVQBGHJZAA+VqCIVIZot-XtWSyJoufIaApZHC9u32qH+4imak02g44jVAOyWQAlPymYKOphsEl2LpCLRCM81ZRCAAmMsAdjL10wIEIjYAeuJc8ZyHbC8WPZXCAAWMt2svlnL14CNwgtttEcjlrslgDMg+HZYXo4bzdbRhnC-nHt0K8IS-76-Hm+n7D7e4yQ6PZYHhAdHDHE6nF-IAFZr8fbw-bx+ywATmHU9Xy3PNyAANmvACKzLWDe0g5cT2fDdJ3A9sq2vJC70IHDjwPODCA-UDz23dgAA5r0Ih8a37ZDj0g0j0PfQDr3-ZCEPvatmKnciOwLIsS0Qw98PgwdeIwmc7U7ISPQI1dq24vCQNQs8WP4u05zkjI-2UjjCDotc1LAzAgA)

### Ungolfed / Explanation

````
// Filters a union of tuples for those with the shortest length
type Shortest<T, K = keyof T> = T extends T ? keyof T extends K ? T : never : 0

type Max<T, U = T> = T extends T ? Exclude<T, Partial<Exclude<U, T>>> : 0

// Converts a number to a tuple of equal length (this version also supports strings)
type NumToTuple<T, N = []> = `${T}` extends `${N["length"]}` ? N : NumToTuple<T, [...N, 0]>

// Returns [A / B, A % B]
type DivRem<A, B, N = []> = A extends [...B, ...infer A] ? DivRem<A, B, [...N, 0]> : [N, A];

type Main<
  _Banks,
  // Convert every number in the input to a tuple
  Banks = { [K in keyof _Banks]: NumToTuple<_Banks[K]> },
  FreeIndTup = Shortest<
    // Find the indices of Input where the value is equal to the max
    { [K in keyof Banks]: Banks[K] extends Max<Banks[number]> ? NumToTuple<K> : never }[number]
  >,
  FreeIndNum = FreeIndTup["length"],
  // The first number is the number of blocks every bank recieves (NewBlockMin)
  // The second is the number of banks that recieve one extra bank (ExtraCount)
  BlockDist = DivRem<Banks[FreeIndNum], NumToTuple<Banks["length"]>>
  // @ts-ignore
> = {
  // Map over Banks:
  [K in keyof Banks]: (
    K extends `${FreeIndNum}`
      // If this Bank is the one being freed, return NewBlockMin
      ? BlockDist[0]
      // Otherwise, sum:
      : [
          // The old value
          ...Banks[K],
          // NewBlockMin
          ...BlockDist[0],
          // 1 if the index meets one of the following critera, or 0 otherwise:
          ...NumToTuple<K> extends
            // Between FreeInd and FreeInd + ExtraCount
            | [...FreeIndTup, ...Partial<BlockDist[1]>]
            // Or, if FreeInd + ExtraCount > Banks.length, less than (FreeInd + ExtraCount) - Banks.length
            | Partial<
                [...FreeIndTup, ...BlockDist[1]] extends [...NumToTuple<Banks["length"]>, ...infer A]
                  ? A
                  : never
              >
            ? [0]
            : []
        ]
  )["length"];
};
```
````

Answer (score 1):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), 205 bytes

```rust
|x:&[_]|{let(mut r,mut v)=(vec![],x.to_vec());while!r.contains(&v){r.push(v.to_vec());let(n,i)=(0..).zip(r.last()?).map(|a|(a.1,!a.0)).max()?;v[!i]=0;for j in!i+1..=!i+n{v[j%x.len()]+=1}}r.push(v);Some(r)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVJRb4IwEH7nVxwmI23sKkzQTML2I/ZIiCEGYw1WVgqaAb@dlXYYXFzWhzvuu7vvvmsRVSn7PYdTyjjC0Fh5JmEPEfTtdePE26RtFIJOlQRBBlvjCNXZzo4TcqXyvFXfCOPwcmB5Zgu6O3OpqErk1LgRtKjKA6ondQMZJ0yRuJRi@sUKJGielhLhd0xPaYHatEUp9YidUhcP0FWlwjq2WRK54f4s4AiM22zuURopx5s6Pj5daZ6pBZJ55HXdOBeHH@dThgTuelAntAarzUCDGC8qSSDl5SUTWJGCE1tmOZfAC4E1ATchoJE/YBX6BDyFj8jShASWI2K6FO6PiGdCVfmAJ8HkR4WhMnhA4HUy5b98oGcauzJlY2qlhxtrpAUTpb7ez3AOZRPJwTjIiF1PtK/GQUtTNrkMV4OGczVR6N@LX08u7JH4BOuHSxrthlMIxmXObTRrNu8dPL/B4GcE7t81vDUsFpCWZSakfYNMvM0@beTskaM7Ma34Rag/Ef/i6Kyu778B)

Answer (score 0):

## Python3, 162 bytes :

```
f=lambda b,c=0,i=0,k=[]:k+[b]if b in k else(f(b[:(i:=b.index((m:=max(b))))]+[0]+b[i+1:],m,i+1,k+[b])if not c else f(b[:(j:=i%len(b))]+[b[j]+1]+b[j+1:],c-1,j+1,k))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY3NCsIwDIDvPkUuQkujbE5RC32S0sOyddj9dGPuMJ9@ZhUMJIEk35fps7zGWDymedsa05cD1SUQVibDwNkZ63SnLLnQAEGI0IHv3140gqwWQRs6h1j7VYhBm6FcBUkOp2zmFNmgcu1wQO6YLJI1cVygShb4WVptwrH3cWeZJNs6le94m/DqlGO7C6TcpjnEhZ/bDOGCcEfInJSH/7hAyBGuqd4QnnzF@@0L)

Answer (score 0):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 78 bytes

```
(a=#;a[[Mod[m+i,Tr[1^a],1]]]++~Do~{i,c=a[[m=Tr@Ordering[-a,1]]]};a[[m]]-=c;a)&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYvLCsIwEEV/ZSBQlE6x9YFKiXShOx8bd0OEIW1tFrFQuwvpr8fYzeHAPdfy2DWWR6M5tCDDgqUomejW12RTg8@BihcrLJRSaTqd@8kZ1DIWVj6H6jHUzWA@b8p4Tvz/a5XKpC55mYR78x3pyhEX3fUkIDtBSyKWkCAIhEMUWFXgXI6wRtgj5B7BbRAKhO3MHcIxjt6HHw)